# The event click is not listen in the emergent react-autosuggest list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autosuggest, mouseclick-event, react-component

When I click on one of the suggestions, the drop-down list only disappears, but the mouse click event can not be heard,

The other events such as mouse focus and keyboard events work perfectly.

In my input code structure and the component in general are within the other component, as I show in part of the code below:

*Parent Component*

```
class SideMenu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      nameSideMenu: "",
    }
  }
  changeName=(value)=>{
    const h=new Side();
    this.setState({nameSideMenu: value})
    this.props.value_return(value);
    h.setState({name: value})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div id="sidebar_menu">
      <h1>Search</h1>
       <CajaTxt value={this.changeName}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

*Child Component*, in the render of the CajaTxt class

```
return(<form>
         <Autosuggest
          id="Name" 
          suggestions={nicknameSuggestions}
          onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.onNicknameSuggestionsFetchRequested}
          onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.onNicknameSuggestionsClearRequested}
          onSuggestionSelected={this.onNicknameSuggestionSelected}
          getSuggestionValue={getSuggestionNickname}
          renderSuggestion={renderSuggestion}
          inputProps={nicknameInputProps}
        />
</form>)
```

Help me please, I've been standing for a long time trying to correct that Bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the prop `focusInputOnSuggestionClick`

https://github.com/moroshko/react-autosuggest#focus-input-on-suggestion-click-prop

It provides ability to lose input focus once a suggestion is clicked.